# Symony 3.1 redirect loop to login form

Tags: security, authentication, symfony, redirect-loop

I'm making a site where everything except the actual login-form should require that the user has logged in.

I'm assuming the issue I'm having is with the security.yml which I've set up like this.

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:      
        provider: auth_provider
        pattern: .*
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /    

access_control:
    - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The firewall does indeed recognise an anonymous user and tries to send him to the login-page. However, the browser halts the request before the login form is rendered due to a redirect-loop. Which I just can't figure out how to solve.

my route file:

```
    site_login:
        path: /login
        defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Security:login }

    site_login_check:
        path: /login_check
        defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Security:login_check }
```

The controller is just:

```
    class SecurityController extends Controller {
        public function loginAction(Request $request) {
            die("here1");
        }

       public function loginCheckAction(Request $request) {
            die("here2");
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to `main` firewall:

```
main:
    anonymous: true
```

and to `access control`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks malcolm!